# can UITableViewController be customized to very compact/small fonts?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to develop a view that is quite compact in terms of font size and row heights.

Is it possible to customize UITableViewController so that the font size / row height you used is whatever?  In fact the more general question is UITableViewController easy to customize such that you can put what ever you want in it and just use it for the framework for showing your customized cells?

Interested in knowing if there are any gottcha's here, and if there were some what would be the next option?  Would it be go straight to having to "draw" your own interface using drawing type commands?

(trying to determine where to dig-in in terms of reading up)

thanks

Comment: u can customize the cell contents whatever u want. cell.textLabel.font

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of your cells are homogenous, you can adjust the `rowHeight` property of `UITableViewController`'s instance of `UITableView`.

`self.tableView.rowHeight = 22.0`

For cells of varying heights, you will have to implement the UITableViewDelegate method, `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

In this method, you will determine how much text needs to be displayed given the indexPath and calculate and return a height value for that row.

Having said all that, Apple's Human Interface Guidelines recommend that UITableViewCell heights should be 44 points at least, given the thickness of human fingers.

Comment: how about changing the fonts of the text you display in there?  I guess the concept of having smaller fonts, then automatic resizing of the row height to this - idea would be it's for viewing with no click through possible

Comment: will mark as answer as Mark got in with the answer to the first part of the question (I've made an answer myself regarding the 2nd part)

Answer (score 2):

depending on the UITableViewCellStyle you are working with you have a textLabel and detailTextLabel elements to work with and you can set font/size/color on them.

`cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];` for an example.

i hear that putting these modifications in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is the proper thing to do.

Comment: thanks Jason - see the answer I posted after following up on your leads

Comment: I agree that heigthforRowAtIndexPath is the proper place for cell height. i thought the question was also towards the font size.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way to set the row height.  Apparently doing this way is better than setting it within the willDisplayCell method due to overheads

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat result;
    result = 20;
    return result;
}
```